# Does this set theory subset proof work?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $A, B$ and $C$ be sets. Let $\mathcal{U}=A \cup B \cup C$. Prove the statement $A \subseteq[(A \cap B) \cup(A \cap(\mathcal{U} \backslash B))]$.

---

Here's my attempt at it. Would this work as proof by contrapositive?

Let $p(x): x \in A$ and $q(x): x \in [(A \cap B) \cup(A \cap(\mathcal{U} \backslash B))]$.

The statement says that $(\forall x)p(x) \Rightarrow q(x)$. Therefore

$$(\forall x)\sim q(x) \Rightarrow \sim p(x)$$

Take any $x \notin [(A \cap B) \cup(A \cap(\mathcal{U} \backslash B))]$. Then $x \notin (A \cap B)$ or $x \notin (A \cap (\mathcal{U} \backslash B))$. It follows that $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$ and $x \notin \mathcal{U} \backslash B$. In particular, $x \notin A$. Therefore $x \notin [(A \cap B) \cup(A \cap(\mathcal{U} \backslash B))] \Rightarrow x \notin A$. Therefore $(\forall x)\sim q(x) \Rightarrow \sim p(x)$ and so it holds true that $(\forall x)p(x) \Rightarrow q(x)$.

Therefore $A \subseteq[(A \cap B) \cup(A \cap(\mathcal{U} \backslash B))] $.

Comment: I think there's an extra $\color{red}{A\subseteq}$ in the second and fourth lines.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 yes you are right, my bad! edited the post to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, there is a small logical intricacy. Saying that $x \notin [(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \mathcal{U} \backslash B)]$ is to say that $x \notin (A \cap B)$ AND $x \notin (A \cap \mathcal{U} \backslash B)$ (the negation of an "or" statement is an "and" statement). Thus $(x \notin A$ or $x \notin B)$ and $(x \notin A$ or $x \notin \mathcal{U} \backslash B)$ (the negation of an "and" statement is an "or" statement). Now this is a statement of the form $(P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$ which is equivalent to saying $P \lor (Q \land R)$, and hence $x \notin A$ or $(x \notin B$ and $x \notin \mathcal{U} \backslash B)$. If $x$ is an element of $\mathcal{U}$, then $x$ either it belongs to $B$, or it belongs to $\mathcal{U} \backslash B$, thus the statement that $x \notin B$ and $x \notin \mathcal{U} \backslash B$ is preposterous. Which is why $x \notin A$. Pretty neat to use the contrapositive for this proof.

I should mention that the assumption that $x$ was an element of $\mathcal{U}$ is crucial. If not, then it is certainly possible that $x \notin B$ and $x \notin \mathcal{U} \backslash B$. So I would change your statement to say $(\forall x \in \mathcal{U}) \; p(x) \Rightarrow q(x)$.

Alternatively, it is not difficult to prove this directly. Let $x$ be any element of $A$. By remarks already made, there are two cases: $x \in B$ or $x \in \mathcal{U} \backslash B$. In either case, we see immediately that $x \in [(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \mathcal{U} \backslash B)]$.

Comment: (+1) congrats for your first answer, and it's wonderful. I didn't have time then, but see it paved the way for you to show up :)